# How do I correctly use mod_rewrite to redirect seo urls?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have these  urls like:

http://example.com/profiles/yourfullname/

But the actual url to get working data is:

http://example.com/profiles?user=yourfullname

I have been reading, and trying to get an understanding of this, but I am clearly missing something in my knowledge.

There is a page, that has a list of links to user profiles, with the seo formatting. However, they clearly do nothing atm, but generate "Page Not Found" errors.

I have tried various versions of the following mod_rewrite code.

```
#rewrite rule for profiles page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^profiles /%1? [R=301]
#end rewrite rule for profiles page

#rewrite rule for profiles page
RewriteRule ^profiles/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ profiles/?user=$1 [NC,L] 
#end rewrite rule for profiles page
```

But clearly I do not understand how this works.

Can someone help me, and provide context?

Thank you!

Added Notes:

This is for a wordpress site.

All I have access is via a plugin that let's me edit an .htaccess file.

This is the additional rules in the htaccess for Wordpress.

```
#rewrite rule for wordpress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#end rewrite rule for wordpress
```

So just to reiterate, I have an existing page, that does http://example.com/profiles/yourfullname/ but I want any page, to stop doing the "Page Not Found" and redirect to http://example.com/profiles?user=yourfullname

Is that clearer?

Thank you again!

Comment: The second rule should work. You have an extra `/` in the rewrite which you *may* not need.

Comment: I doubt that, but I could find out. Which / is the extra slash? I tried the second rule, but everytime, it gave me page not found. 

BTW, this is htcaccess for a Wordpress site.

Comment: Do you have other rules in the file that might be conflicting?

Comment: I added the rest of the rules. And updated the description, I hope that was helpful.

Comment: I have hand-modified the .htcaccess file located in the root of the Wordpress site. Then uploaded, then tried to go to http://example.com/profiles/yourfullname/ but all i get is "Page Not Found". How can I tell if internally it redirects to the right url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the cause of the redirect problem had nothing to do with mod_rewrite.

This was for a wordpress site and I could not figure out how the previous developer had setup the correct url to work, since there were no rewrite rules.

But apparently they had modified the 404 template for the WordPress theme they were using.

Thanks to everyone for their help!